# UWP TemplatePart in ComboBox

Tags: combobox, uwp

Why there is no TemplatePartAttribute in ComboBox?

UWP:

```
[Composable(typeof(IComboBoxFactory), CompositionType.Public, 65536, "Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract")]
[ContractVersion(typeof(UniversalApiContract), 65536)]
[MarshalingBehavior(MarshalingType.Agile)]
[Static(typeof(IComboBoxStatics2), 65536, "Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract")]
[Static(typeof(IComboBoxStatics), 65536, "Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract")]
[Threading(ThreadingModel.Both)]
[WebHostHidden]
public class ComboBox : Selector, IComboBox, IComboBoxOverrides, IComboBox2
```

WPF:

```
[Localizability(LocalizationCategory.ComboBox)]
[StyleTypedProperty(Property = "ItemContainerStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(ComboBoxItem))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_EditableTextBox", Type = typeof(TextBox))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_Popup", Type = typeof(Popup))]
public class ComboBox : Selector
```

Comment: What is your real problem? Why you need `TemplatePartAttribute`? `TemplatePartAttribute` is just not used in UWP.

Comment: Thx for you answer.I'm just learning how to create customcontrol in uwp.

Comment: [TemplatePartAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.TemplatePartAttribute) is also available in UWP, you can use it in your custom control. However, this is no mandatory. You can always decide whether to use or not. ;)